# How to combine if-let statements in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have the following enum, which represents cells in a 2d game world

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum Cell {
    Empty,
    Soil,
    Metal,
    Diamond(Falling),
    Boulder(Falling),
    Player,
    Enemy,
    Exit
}
```

where Falling is also an enum:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum Falling {
    True,
    False
}
```

I also have a second enum:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum PlayerInput {
    None,
    Up,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right
}
```

I want to implement the following logic in Rust, according to which a boolean called `canMove` will be set either true or false:

```
let cell; // is of type Cell
let input; // is of type PlayerInput

if cell is Player or Metal, FALSE
if cell is Boulder(_) or Diamond(_) and input is Down, FALSE
if cell is Boulder(NotFalling) and input is Up, FALSE
if cell is Boulder(_) and input is Right or Left, and oneMoreCondition(cell,input) is true, FALSE
otherwise TRUE
```

Now that if let statements don't support && operators, I'm left with match statements, which will still require nested if let statements, and the resulting code will be less readable. What is the idiomatic way to solve this? Or perhaps I'm misusing enums. Please propose a better solution please

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/929

Comment: I've seen this, but it doesn't propose a solution. I tried 
```
if let (Cell::Boulder(_) | Cell::Diamond(_), PlayerInput::Down) = (next, self.current_input) { ... }
```
but compiler says "or-pattern syntax is experimental" and won't compile

Comment: Side note: why do you have `Falling` with values `True`/`False` instead of simply using a `bool`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `match` and match the two variables as a tuple:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum Cell {
    Empty,
    Soil,
    Metal,
    Diamond(Falling),
    Boulder(Falling),
    Player,
    Enemy,
    Exit
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum Falling {
    True,
    False
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum PlayerInput {
    None,
    Up,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right
}

fn oneMoreCondition(cell: Cell, input: PlayerInput) -> bool {
    // Any arbitrary logic here.
    true
}

fn canMove(cell: Cell, input: PlayerInput) -> bool {
    match (cell, input) {
        (Cell::Player, _) | (Cell::Metal, _) => false,
        (Cell::Boulder(_), PlayerInput::Down) | (Cell::Diamond(_), PlayerInput::Down) => false,
        (Cell::Boulder(Falling::False), PlayerInput::Up) => false,
        (Cell::Boulder(_), PlayerInput::Right) | (Cell::Boulder(_), PlayerInput::Left) if oneMoreCondition(cell, input) => false,
        _ => true,
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", canMove(Cell::Player, PlayerInput::Left));
    println!("{}", canMove(Cell::Boulder(Falling::True), PlayerInput::Down));
    println!("{}", canMove(Cell::Boulder(Falling::False), PlayerInput::Up));
    println!("{}", canMove(Cell::Boulder(Falling::False), PlayerInput::Right));
    println!("{}", canMove(Cell::Enemy, PlayerInput::Left));
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> false
> false
> false
> false
> true
> ```

Comment: input == x won't work because Right,Left,Up,Down are parts of an enum. and as far as i know, I can't use if let in that case

Comment: Note that you probably also want to derive the `Eq`, `PartialEq` and `Debug` traits.